# Getting the error android.view.InflateException for the Android Cropper

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview, android-view, android-custom-view

I am trying to use the android cropper library at https://github.com/edmodo/cropper . I have imported the 'cropper.jar' file properly in the libs folder as well.
But, when I'm trying to use the custom view CropImageView (this is defined in the cropper library in the package com.edmondo.cropper.CropImageView) in my XML layout:

```
<com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView 
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I am getting the error:

```
02-04 19:14:16.239: W/dalvikvm(28620): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1378 (CropImageView) in Lcom/edmodo/cropper/R$styleable;
02-04 19:14:16.239: D/dalvikvm(28620): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0011
02-04 19:14:16.239: W/dalvikvm(28620): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1377 (crop_image_view) in Lcom/edmodo/cropper/R$layout;
02-04 19:14:16.239: D/dalvikvm(28620): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0004
02-04 19:14:16.239: I/dalvikvm(28620): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0560 at 0x0b in Lcom/edmodo/cropper/CropImageView;.init
02-04 19:14:16.239: I/dalvikvm(28620): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x055f at 0x1a in Lcom/edmodo/cropper/CropImageView;.init
02-04 19:14:16.239: D/AndroidRuntime(28620): Shutting down VM
02-04 19:14:16.239: W/dalvikvm(28620): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41527ba8)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620): Process: com.vishal.cameragallerypics, PID: 28620
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vishal.cameragallerypics/com.vishal.cameragallerypics.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at com.vishal.cameragallerypics.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:120)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    ... 11 more
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    ... 25 more
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.edmodo.cropper.R$styleable
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    at com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView.<init>(CropImageView.java:84)
02-04 19:14:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(28620):    ... 28 more
```

I have gone through many questions regarding the same issue, but none of the answers could help me solve the problem. It would be great if somebody can help me out with the issue.

Comment: hey, i'm having the some issue! any solution?

Answer (score 1):

i get the same error today (**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.edmodo.cropper.R$styleable**) but i build the 'cropper.jar' from source using Android Gradle Plugin. Although we maybe in different troubles, hope my finding can give you a hint:

1. go to the output folder: **{your-module-dir}/build/generated/source/r/release/com/edmodo/cropper/R.java** and see whether the missing class is present.
2. check the build system config and find out why the class is missing (e.g. check other work libs' output folder and find out the differences).

finally i find out i use the wrong applicationId in gradle build file, so the generated R.java is placed in the wrong package (com.edmonod.R.java not com.edmonod.**cropper**.R.java).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue and in my case,It was the old cropper library I was using before adding "com.edmodo.cropper" library.What actually happening is when we add this library to gradle,It picks up some files from the Old cropper with same name.Resulting the issue was faced.As soon as i removed the old cropper library,Everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

At the example the definition at XML file is as follows:

```
 com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        custom:imageResource="@drawable/butterfly"
```

I had the same error when I add `custom:imageResource="@drawable/butterfly"`. I solved it when I removed it, but adding on code:

```
// Initialize components
cropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);
cropImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.butterfly);
```